# not able to debug express app in node-inspector

Tags: node.js, debugging, express, node-inspector

I'm trying to debug my ejs app by: 
`npm run debug`
Folowing is the scripts from package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "debug": "node --debug ./bin/www"
  },
```

in node-inspector, I am getting following error:

[image]

Comment: This is an incompatibility between node-inspector and the latest version of node.js.  There's a manual patch you can make to node-inspector to work around it.  I ran into this myself a few months ago and applied the patch and it worked.  You should first make sure you have the latest version of node-inspector in case the issue has been fixed.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/907

Comment: Patch here: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/pull/938/commits/04ae7f4dc4e368cdca85b4fa505df50e47253aeb

Comment: Thanks to all of you. As per the discussions, all are telling to downgrade node. But I don't want to do that. I got  different solution. I am using Visual studio code to debug now. It is working properly.